# OpenLayers 2 - How to get coordinates for selected feature (point)

Tags: javascript, extjs, html-lists, openlayers, gis

I'd like to get coordinates of selected point on my layer.

I found solution like this:

```
myLayer.features[0].geometry.getVertices()[0]
```

but this is not certainly what I need, because it works only for one, concrete point.

I want to choose the point by clicking mouse and then get info about this.

Is it any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found solution for me:
 (I'm using GeoExt). I've just added to my code it:

```
 new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("warstwa", {
     styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
         'default': styl
     }),
     protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
         url: '',
         format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
     }),
     strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],      
         eventListeners: {
             featureselected: function(e) {
             var xValue = Ext.getCmp('xValue');
             var yValue = Ext.getCmp('yValue');
             xValue.setValue(e.feature.geometry.getVertices()[0].x);
             yValue.setValue(e.feature.geometry.getVertices()[0].y);
        }
    });
```

...and it works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

this may help you:

```
new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(layer,{
    hover:true,
    eventListeners:{
        onSelect:function(e){
            alert(e.feature.geometry.getVertices()[0].x);
            alert(e.feature.geometry.getVertices()[0].y);
        }
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can found the samples of the OpenLayers Cookbook at http://acanimal.github.io/Openlayers-Cookbook/ (source https://github.com/acanimal/Openlayers-Cookbook) which contains samples for feature selection.

Cheers.